# Use multiple contains functions in if statement (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

Is there a way to use multiple "contains(array, value)" functions in an if statement? I have a query that stores in the results in an array. If the results are nil I perform a set of operations. If, however, the array is not nil I'd like to check to see if certain objects appear in it:

```
var user: PFUser?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //get the two players
        if let user = user{

            var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "Game")
            userQuery.whereKey("user1", equalTo: user)
            userQuery.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            var userQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Game")
            userQuery2.whereKey("user2", equalTo: user)
            userQuery2.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            var currentUserQuery = PFQuery(className: "Game")
            currentUserQuery.whereKey("user1", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
            currentUserQuery.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            var currentUserQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "Game")
            currentUserQuery2.whereKey("user2", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
            currentUserQuery2.whereKey("isActive", equalTo: true)

            var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, userQuery2, currentUserQuery, currentUserQuery2])
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if error == nil{

                    //if there are no active games, start new game
                    if results == nil{

                        //start game code


                    } else if contains(results, user) as [AnyObject]! && contains(results, PFUser.currentUser()) as [AnyObject]! {

                        println(results)
                    }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Using the && operator is returning an error on the line: `Cannot invoke '&&' with an argument of type '([AnyObject]!,[AnyObject]!)'`. Any ideas on how I can test to see if the user and PFUser.current_user() objects are found in the array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are trying to cast result of **contains** func call which is Bool in to array of AnyObjects's.

What you need to do instead is just to compare results of **contains(results, user)** and contains(results, PFUser.currentUser()) functions calls. But it wont compile.

In order to make your compiler happy you need to cast **results** array to array of **[PFUser]**

See code:

```
if let users = results as? [PFUser] {
    if contains(users, user) && contains(users, PFUser.currentUser())  {
       println(users)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I removed the else if statement and instead put in the if statement above and I get an error `Cannot invoke '&&' with an argument of type '($T4, $T9)'`. What does this mean?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the return type of `(results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void `. I think the Void might be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick. So this pretty much works like an else if, since the initial if statement wouldn't pass?